# Unable to print page using jsPDF properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf

I m using javascript to create pdf dynamically but unable to use it properly ,i tried html2canvas but it gives only one page that is front page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.3/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <title> Test </title>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="" onclick="downloadPDF()">Download pdf</button>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
<script>

    var data = [{
        "title": "'Nobble' egg drop and sweet corn soup with abalone",
        "recipeCategories": "retail1",
        "criticalDetails": "",
        "allergies": [{
            "eggs": false,
            "milk": false,
            "fish": false,
            "peanut": false,
            "shellfish": false,
            "soy": false,
            "treenuts": false,
            "wheat": false,
            "seems seeds": false,
            "sulphur dioxide and sulphites": false,
            "cerely": false,
            "cerials containing gluten": false,
            "crustacea": false,
            "lupin": false,
            "molluscs": false,
            "mustard": false
        }],

        "intolerance": [{
            "mustard": false,
            "lactose": false,
            "yeast": false
        }],
        "cautions": "This allergence,Intolerence and Dietry informations has not been verified.",
        "ingredients": [{ "quantity": "200 grams", "details": "Egg white albuen frozen 10kg-pace farm", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "10 grams", "details": "shalliot green bunch", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "10 grams", "details": "ginger peeled", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "5 grams", "details": "carrot peeled", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "10 centilitre", "details": "VEGETABLE stock", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "0.10 * Each", "details": "G/OCEAN/ABALONE (1PC) 150 GRM-TIN", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "30 grams", "details": "corn cobbettes super sweet frozen", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "1 grams", "details": "Herb coriander bunch -100 gram", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "5 grams", "details": "Egg white albuen frozen 10kg-pace farm", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "5 grams", "details": "flour cornflor maze", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" }
        ],
        "methods": [
            "decaned abandalone,keep the juice from the tin,freeze abalone then slice 1 min thin",
            "trim corn cobette,keep the corn stalk,mince ginger",
            "pick coriander,julienne green shallott,dice carrot in 5 mm dice",
            "make vegetable stock with corn stalk,boil the turn tto stimmer for 1 hour,strain,add in the abandalone stock,boil and keep on simmer",
            "saute carrot,cream corn and corn cannel(from the cobelette) with mince ginger,add in egg white and season"
        ],
        "storingDetails": {
            "BatchNumber": "wreq",
            "ProducedBy": "",
            "date": "",
            "temparature": "",
            "sealChecked": "",
            "timeIntoFridge": "",
            "tasted": ""
        },
        "details": {
            "yield": "1.0 1* each serving",
            "cost per serving": "",
            "scaled recipe cost per serving": "",
            "recipe selling price": ""
        }

    },
    {
        "title": "'Nobble' egg drop and sweet corn soup with abalone",
        "recipeCategories": "retail1",
        "criticalDetails": "",
        "allergies": [{
            "eggs": false,
            "milk": false,
            "fish": false,
            "peanut": false,
            "shellfish": false,
            "soy": false,
            "treenuts": false,
            "wheat": false,
            "seems seeds": false,
            "sulphur dioxide and sulphites": false,
            "cerely": false,
            "cerials containing gluten": false,
            "crustacea": false,
            "lupin": false,
            "molluscs": false,
            "mustard": false
        }],

        "intolerance": [{
            "mustard": false,
            "lactose": false,
            "yeast": false
        }],
        "cautions": "This allergence,Intolerence and Dietry informations has not been verified.",
        "ingredients": [{ "quantity": "200 grams", "details": "Egg white albuen frozen 10kg-pace farm", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "10 grams", "details": "shalliot green bunch", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "10 grams", "details": "ginger peeled", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "5 grams", "details": "carrot peeled", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "10 centilitre", "details": "VEGETABLE stock", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "0.10 * Each", "details": "G/OCEAN/ABALONE (1PC) 150 GRM-TIN", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "30 grams", "details": "corn cobbettes super sweet frozen", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "1 grams", "details": "Herb coriander bunch -100 gram", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "5 grams", "details": "Egg white albuen frozen 10kg-pace farm", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" },
        { "quantity": "5 grams", "details": "flour cornflor maze", "cost": "$100.00", "refId": "" }
        ],
        "methods": [
            "decaned abandalone,keep the juice from the tin,freeze abalone then slice 1 min thin",
            "trim corn cobette,keep the corn stalk,mince ginger",
            "pick coriander,julienne green shallott,dice carrot in 5 mm dice",
            "make vegetable stock with corn stalk,boil the turn tto stimmer for 1 hour,strain,add in the abandalone stock,boil and keep on simmer",
            "saute carrot,cream corn and corn cannel(from the cobelette) with mince ginger,add in egg white and season"
        ],
        "storingDetails": {
            "BatchNumber": "wreq",
            "ProducedBy": "",
            "date": "",
            "temparature": "",
            "sealChecked": "",
            "timeIntoFridge": "",
            "tasted": ""
        },
        "details": {
            "yield": "1.0 1* each serving",
            "cost per serving": "",
            "scaled recipe cost per serving": "",
            "recipe selling price": ""
        }

    }

    ];


    function getData() {


        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var left = document.createElement('div');
            left.className = 'left';
            var right = document.createElement('div');
            right.className = "right"
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            container.className = 'container'
            var content = document.getElementById('content');


            var heading = document.createElement("div");
            heading.innerHTML = data[i].title;
            heading.className = 'left-heading'
            left.appendChild(heading);

            var categoryDiv = document.createElement("div");
            categoryDiv.className = 'categories'

            var p = document.createElement('p')
            p.innerHTML = `<b>Recipe categories</b>  : ${data[i].recipeCategories}`;
            categoryDiv.appendChild(p)

            var p = document.createElement('p')
            p.innerHTML = `<b>Critical Details</b>  : ${data[i].criticalDetails}`;
            categoryDiv.appendChild(p)

            left.appendChild(categoryDiv)

            var heading2 = document.createElement("h5");
            heading2.className = 'mb-10'
            heading2.innerHTML = 'Allergence:'
            left.appendChild(heading2);

            var alphadiv = document.createElement('div')
            alphadiv.className = 'grid-container'
            alphadiv.classList.add('mb-10')
            var allergens = Object.entries(data[i].allergies[0])

            for (const [prop, val] of allergens) {
                let newdiv = document.createElement('div')

                var input = document.createElement('input')
                input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
                newdiv.appendChild(input)

                let span = document.createElement('span')
                span.classList = 'ml-5 uppercase'
                span.innerText = `${prop}`

                newdiv.appendChild(span)
                alphadiv.appendChild(newdiv)
            }
            left.appendChild(alphadiv)

            var intolerance = document.createElement("h4");
            intolerance.className = 'categories'
            intolerance.innerHTML = 'Intolerance:'
            left.appendChild(intolerance)

            var betadiv = document.createElement('div')
            betadiv.className = 'grid-container'
            betadiv.classList.add('mb-10')

            var intolerance = Object.entries(data[i].intolerance[0]);

            for (const [prop, val] of intolerance) {

                let newdiv = document.createElement('div')

                var input = document.createElement('input')
                input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
                newdiv.appendChild(input)

                let span = document.createElement('span')
                span.classList = 'ml-5 uppercase'
                span.innerText = `${prop}`

                newdiv.appendChild(span)
                betadiv.appendChild(newdiv)
            }
            left.appendChild(betadiv)

            var caution = document.createElement('div');
            caution.className = 'caution'
            caution.innerHTML = `<b>Caution</b> : ${data[i].cautions}`
            left.appendChild(caution)

            let hr = document.createElement('hr')
            hr.className = 'mt-10'
            right.appendChild(hr)

            let table = document.createElement('table')
            table.className = 'w-100'
            let thead = document.createElement('thead');
            thead.className = 'mb-10'
            thead.innerHTML = `
            <tr style='margin-bottom:20px !important'>
                <th>Ingredients</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>RefId#</th>
            </tr>
            `
            table.appendChild(thead)

            let ingredients = data[i].ingredients;
            let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
            ingredients.forEach(item => {
                let tr = document.createElement('tr')
                tr.innerHTML = `
                <td> ${item.quantity}</td>
                <td> ${item.details}</td>
                <td class='cost'> ${item.cost}</td>
                <td style='min-width:80px'> <hr></td>
            `
                tbody.appendChild(tr)
            })
            table.appendChild(tbody)
            right.appendChild(table);

            let newhr = document.createElement('hr');
            newhr.className = 'mt-10'
            right.appendChild(newhr)

            var heading3 = document.createElement("h5");
            heading3.className = 'mb-5'
            heading3.innerHTML = '<b>Method:</b>'
            right.appendChild(heading3)

            let methods = data[i].methods;
            let ol = document.createElement("ol");
            ol.className = 'pl-15'
            ol.classList.add('mb-10')

            methods.forEach(item => {
                let listItems = document.createElement('li');
                listItems.innerHTML = item
                ol.appendChild(listItems);
            })
            right.appendChild(ol);

            let tableData = data[i].storingDetails

            let table1 = document.createElement('table')
            table1.className = 'table-border'
            let table2 = document.createElement('table')
            table2.className = 'table-border mb-10'

            table1.innerHTML = `
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Batch Number</th>   
          <th>Produced By</th>    
          <th>Date</th>   
          <th>Temperature</th>   
        </tr>    
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>${tableData.BatchNumber}</td>  
            <td>${tableData.ProducedBy}</td>  
            <td><${tableData.date}/td>  
            <td><${tableData.temperature}/td>  
          </tr> 
        </tbody>
        `

            table2.innerHTML = `
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Seal Checked</th>   
          <th> Time into fridge</th>    
          <th>Out of Fridge</th>   
          <th>Tasted</th>   
        </tr>    
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>${tableData.BatchNumber}</td>  
            <td>${tableData.ProducedBy}</td>  
            <td><${tableData.date}/td>  
            <td><${tableData.temperature}/td>  
          </tr> 
        </tbody>
        `
            right.appendChild(table1)
            right.appendChild(table2)

            let details = Object.entries(data[i].details)

            let div = document.createElement('div');
            for (const [prop, val] of details) {
                let p = document.createElement('p');
                p.innerHTML = `<b class='uppercase'>${prop}:</b> ${val}`;
                div.appendChild(p);
            }
            right.appendChild(div)

            container.appendChild(left);
            container.appendChild(right);
            content.appendChild(container)

        }


    }
    getData();

    function downloadPDF() {
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#container': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
     var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a3');

        pdf.fromHTML( document.getElementById('content').innerHTML,15,15,{'width':179,'elementHandlers':specialElementHandlers})
        pdf.save('test.pdf');    
    }

</script>

</html>
```

I want to print html content into pdf form , but it is no loading css properly and tables are not regular.I don't know why ??

I mentioned attachment of pdf [image]

Below is the css part which is not including during the print page .

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     color:rgb(58, 57, 57);
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.container .left{
    width:80%;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}

.container .right{
    width:80%;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}

.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:auto auto auto;
}

.mt-10{
    margin:10px auto
}

.mb-10{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mb-5{
    margin-bottom: 5px
}

.ml-5{
    margin-left:5px
}

.pl-20{
    padding-left:20px
}

.pl-15{
    padding-left:15px
}

.table-border thead tr,.table-border thead tr th,.table-border tbody tr, .table-border tbody tr td{
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0.95em;   
}

.table-border thead tr,.table-border thead tr,.table-border tbody tr, .table-border tbody tr td,.table-border thead tr th{
    padding:5px 10px;
    min-width:200px;
}

table thead tr th{
    text-align:justify
}

.left-heading{
    padding:10px 20px 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size:1.5em
}

.categories{
    font-size:0.8em;
    margin:10px 0
}

.uppercase{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size:0.8em
}

.caution{
    font-size:0.8em;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.w-100{
    width: 100%
}

ol li{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.cost{
    font-size:0.9em
}
```